# SQUARESPACE (CSS): Absolute positioning causes blurry images in IE

Tags: css, css-position, internet-explorer-11, absolute, squarespace

I'm customizing the CSS of a Squarespace blog for work. All I need to add is a Title on Hover. I found a CSS code which does this and everything seemed to work, untill I tried Internet Explorer. (I took the code from here: [squarefront addon](http://squarefront.com/addons/content-overlays-summary-gallery-blocks) )

For some reason in IE all thumbnails get blurred. The hover works fine though. The odd thing is that if I click on Inspect Element it immediately sharpens all images. But if I refresh they get blurry again.

I tried removing bits of code to see what causes this and it looks like the "Position: Absolute;" element is causing the problems. Is there a way I can fix this? In FF,Chrome and Safari it works without problems.

```
This is the code I have now:
//------------------------------------*\

/* CONTENT OVERLAYS - SUMMARY & GALLERY BLOCKS
--------------------------------------

// ADDON VARIABLES

// Background Opacity 
@content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-start: .0;
@content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-stop: .55;

// Gradient Background
.summary-block-gradient-background {
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
}

// CSS Animation Speed
@transition-speed: 150ms;

// CSS Transition
.transition-all  { 
    -webkit-transition: all @transition-speed ease !important;
    -moz-transition: all @transition-speed ease !important;
  -ms-transition: all @transition-speed ease !important;
    -o-transition: all @transition-speed ease !important;
    transition: all @transition-speed ease !important;
}

// Summary Block Code
.sqs-block-summary-v2 {

    .summary-block-setting-design-autogrid,
  .summary-block-setting-design-autocolumns {

        // Wildcard Transition Animation for CSS Attributes
        *, *:before, *:after {
            .transition-all;
        }

        .summary-item {

            .summary-thumbnail-container {
                margin: 0;

                .summary-thumbnail {
                    &:before {
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    z-index: 2;
                    opacity: @content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-start;
                    .summary-block-gradient-background;

                    }
                }
            }


                  //hover states van de tekst
            &:hover {
                .summary-title{ //wijziging
              opacity: 1;

            }
             }
          &:not(:hover) {
                .summary-title{ //wijziging
              opacity: 0;

            }
             }

//positionering van de titel top is hoogte, translate3d is out of frame afstand

           .summary-content {
            position: absolute;
              top: 30%;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              z-index: 5;
                display: -webkit-flex;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
              -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              -webkit-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
              padding: 25px;
              pointer-events: none;
               // -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
               // transform: translate3d(0,0%,0);
                opacity: 1;

//lettertype titel
              .summary-title {

                width: 100%;
                font-size: 2.25rem;
                font-weight: 200;

                a {
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                }
                }
                .summary-excerpt {
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 600px;
                    opacity: 0;

                    p, ol, ul {
                        color: #FFFFFF;
                    }
                }
            }

            &:hover {
                     .summary-thumbnail-container {

                     .summary-thumbnail {
            &:before {
                    opacity: @content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-stop;
                     }
                                    }
                                             }
                    .summary-content {
                    //-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
                    //transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

                    .summary-excerpt {
                        opacity: 1;
                                     }
                                }
                     }
        }   
  }
}

// Gallery Block Code
.sqs-block-gallery {

  .sqs-gallery-block-grid {

        // Wildcard Transition Animation for CSS Attributes
        *, *:before, *:after {
            .transition-all;
        }

        .slide {
            position: relative;

            .image-slide-anchor {
                &:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 2;
                opacity: @content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-start;
                .summary-block-gradient-background;

                }
            }

            .margin-wrapper {
                .image-slide-title {
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 25px;
                z-index: 5;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 2.25rem;
                font-weight: 200;
                color: #FFFFFF;
              pointer-events: none;
                //    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
                 //   transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
              }
            }

            &:hover {

                .image-slide-anchor {
                    &:before {
                        opacity: @content-overlay-hover-effect-opacity-stop;
                    }
                }

                .margin-wrapper {
                    .image-slide-title {
                      // -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,40%,0);
                      //  transform: translate3d(0,40%,0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

You can find the blog on [www.obsessedwithkms.com](http://www.obsessedwithkms.com)

Any help is much appreciated.

Wilbert

Comment: People tend not to be keen on debugging people's sites for them. Suggest making a JSFiddle to demonstrate the specific issue.

Comment: like this? (open in IE to see the issue): https://jsfiddle.net/wf7n64a1/3/